# Cannot access public function from different QML file

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

Qt 6.2.0 Ubuntu 20.04

**Content.qml**

```
PathView {
    id: view

    function myFunc(type) {
        console.log(type)
    }
}
```

**Main.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window

    Item {
        id: item

        Content {
          id: content
        }
    }

    Item {
       content.myFunc(1) // <-- Expected token :
    }
}
```

What is the right syntax to call `myFunc()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing logic inside a QML item is not allowed, you can call myFunc under a clickable area like following

```
 MouseArea {
        onClicked: {
            content.myFunc()
        }
    }
```

you can read more for to get a better understandings from [Implementing the Game Logic](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-tutorials-samegame-samegame3-example.html)